# PHP displays JQuery $.post variables as NULL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

I can't find out what i am doing wrong, i've been googling this issue for over 3 days now and cannot find anything that helps or works.. Any suggestions?

AjaxTest.php (the HTML and JavaScript page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rchar").submit(function(event){
        alert("hahahaha");
        var request;
        // abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);
        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // fire off the request to /form.php
        request = $.ajax({
        url: 'postregister.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }   
    });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#navigation").html(serializedData);
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // prevent default posting of form
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
 <body>
    <form id="rchar" method="POST" action="postregister.php">
    <h3>Test Form!</h3>
    <table id="leftalignment1">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" size="35px" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" name="name"><input type="hidden" value="Test" id="hidden" name="hidden"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" size="35px" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table><br><br>
    <input action="submit" value="  Register  " id="submit" type="submit"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

postregister.php (The page where the variables are posted and displayed)

```
<?php
echo $_POST;
var_dump($oldname);
  $oldname = $_POST['hidden'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
$title = "Your password is: " . $password;
  echo $title . "<br>" . $password . "<br>Your old name was: <br>" . $oldname;
?>
```

The result printed into the JavaScript console is

```
ArrayNULL
Your password is: <br><br>Your old name was: <br>
```

Note that NONE of this code was edited, this is how the code actually looks in its current form.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Start by trying [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/fauHm/) instead, and tell us what the console.logs says. Also, you can't echo an array in PHP, and $_POST is an array, so remove that and the var_dump before you try it.

Comment: @adeneo It just replies with "Your password is: <br><br>Your old name was: <br> " now

Comment: You serialize all the form fields, but I think you should just serialize the form; that is, `$form.serialize()` over `$form.find("input, select, button, textarea");`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I already have that in there.

Comment: What does print_r($_REQUEST) look like?

Comment: @user2647338 Array
(
    [__utma] => 66603262.1215597233.1375133809.1375317616.1375560839.7
    [__utmc] => 66603262
    [__utmz] => 66603262.1375133809.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
)

Comment: Are you accessing the `postregister.php` directly? This code works like it should. But if you are going directly to `postregister.php` in your browser it will not work since your values were posted using ajax.